# Graph implementation in C++

Tags: c++, graph

I want to do some operations on a graph. Before I start operations I have tried to construct the graph. But I'm not sure if I did correctly. Can you say if I'm in the right direction?
The input will be like this :

- A
- B
- C
- A B 1
- A C 2
- B C 3

I have put nodes into a char vector like this :

```
vector<char> nodes;
```

And I have put edges into a Edge vector like this :

```
class Edge
{
    private : 
    int length;
    char node1; 
    char node2;

    public : 
    Edge(int l, char n1, char n2);

};
```

Comment: Better post a [SSCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the efficient way you can implement a graph.
Vertexes and Edges are different entities, so they need to be represented by different data structures.

Like 2 classes : class Vertex and class Edge.

Also concept of cyclic dependency must be used. For further details, please check this site:

http://badboys.7p.com/notes/Graph%20-%20Linked%20Implementation%20(C++).htm

Comment: StackOverflow is not a link dump. Try to provide full answers and use links to augment them.

Comment: Ok i will edit the answer. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be on the way to a valid solution.

To my knowledge, there are two canonical approached to implementing graph data structures.
The first is with an edge list, which seems to be the approach you have chosen. The graph structure is represented by a list of edges with optional weights. Note, you may want to add more to this to make for a more efficient structure, depending on the uses for your graph. For example, if you need to find a list of all neighbors of a node quickly, it may be better to store an edge list for each incident node.

A second approach would be to represent the graph as a matrix-like structure where the entry (i,j) is either a boolean representing whether there is an edge from node i to node j.

Answer (score 0):

First you need a simple Node class. The node class usually contains a linked list (use a list!) of child nodes. In your case you are using a graph with edges so your nodes should contain linked lists of edges that connect to children. Also, I'm not sure why you are using `char` to reference your nodes, you should be using a Node class with Node references.

Comment: Do not use `vector` for lists, use `list`. D'oh.

Comment: @Griwes see edit. You are right, vector is array based, you want a link based structure.